# Block Order on Home Page

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks

I have a scenario where i need to place two blocks one after the other in default handle.
One block make use of template file while other use static block. Issue i am facing is ordering of the block. I want block with template file first and then static block.

code for layout file is as below

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="practiceblock" after="page_content_heading"
                   template="blockpractice/newblock.phtml"/>
            <block type="cms/block" name="practiceCMSBlock" after="-">
                <action method="setBlockId">
                    <block_id>practiceCMSBlock</block_id>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

I have used after="-" for static block but is still show as below

[image]

Any clue for above?

Comment: If your problem was solved, please select one of the answers as "accepted" to mark this question as solved. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code that I have used to show template block and then cms block.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="practiceblock" template="blockpractice/newblock.phtml"/>
            <block type="cms/block" name="practiceCMSBlock" after="practiceblock">
                <action method="setBlockId">
                    <block_id>practiceCMSBlock</block_id>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Output is

```
Template Block
CMS Block
```

Comment: I tried this too. But not working for me.

Comment: @Rakesh If everyone pretty much is giving the same answer and it's not working for you, consider that it is working for you, but because of JS/CSS in your site it's rendered differently in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the static block to be displayed after template file your code should be something like this

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="practiceblock" after="page_content_heading"
                   template="blockpractice/newblock.phtml"/>
            <block type="cms/block" name="practiceCMSBlock" after="practiceblock">
                <action method="setBlockId">
                    <block_id>practiceCMSBlock</block_id>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I have already tried this solution, but no luck. Out remains the same . I have my cache disabled.

Comment: this should work. I don't see any error in there. Can you please tell me where are you placing this code ?? Also instead of self closing block try using </block>

Comment: I am placing this code in layout file.

Comment: try this thing `block type="core/template" name="practiceblock" as="testblock" after="page_content_heading"
                   template="blockpractice/newblock.phtml"/>`  and add `testblock` in after instead of `practiceblock`

Comment: Can you please try it your self Once .. I have tried all the solution listed so far,But still order is incorrect. I am using a fresh copy of Magento 1.8.

Comment: okay i'll check it and let you know on it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using layout it is also possible to just `echo` the CMS block content at the end of template file `blockpractice/newblock.phtml` just add the following lines, to keep everything simple and in order.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('practiceCMSBlock')->toHtml();
```

Comment: For this code to work i need to define new Block/Controller Class. which i don't want to. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: No, just add the above line in template file it should be working. There is no need to define Block/Controller! @Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work to order block with template file first and then static block:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="practiceblock" before="practiceCMSBlock" template="blockpractice/newblock.phtml"/>
        <block type="cms/block" name="practiceCMSBlock" after="practiceblock">
            <action method="setBlockId">
                <block_id>practiceCMSBlock</block_id>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Hope this will work for you. :)